# Задача "Уникальная строка"

Tags: c++

Программа не проходит 3 тест.Вот условие:

> Текстовый файл состоит из N строк (1≤N≤50000). Длина строки не превышает 255 символов. В этом файле есть строка, которая встречается один раз, все остальные строчки повторяются, причем четное количество раз. Необходимо найти эту уникальную строку (или исключить все повторяющиеся).
> Вход содержит одну или более строк. Список завершается символом "#". Этот символ находится отдельно, первым в последней строке и к списку не относится.
> Выход содержит уникальную строку

Пример ввода

```
    repeat
    unique
    repeat
    #
```

Пример вывода

```
    unique
```

Я решал вот так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
bool mask[25002];
string ar[25002];
int n = 0;
void push(char t[255])
{
    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++)
    {
        if(ar[i] == t)
        {
            mask[i] = true;
            return;
        }
    }
    ar[n] = t;
    n++;
}
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
    char t[255];
    while(cin >> t)
    {
        if(t[0] == '#') break;
        push(t);
    }
    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++)
        if(!mask[i])
        {
            cout << ar[i] <<endl;

        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: fori1ton Тк все строки кроме одной повторяются, то кол-во разных строк всего 50000 / 2.
С библиотекой STL не знаком. Думаю в задаче наверняка можно обойтись без нее.

Answer (score 8):

Раз длина строк ограничена, то можем считать, что все строки имеют длину строго 256 символов (что бы хранить 0 в конце). Если строка короче 255 символов, просто набиваем нулями (не символом нуля, а `'\0'`) до конца. Теперь, нужна будт одна строка для хранения промежуточного результата. Ее инициализируем нулями (именно всю, все 256 символов).

теперь, раз одинаковые строки встречаются четное кол-во раз, а нужная строка - только один раз, можно применить мою любимую операцию xor.

А теперь алгоритм (код напишете сами).

```
char[256] a;// для работы и результата в конце.
char[256] b;// для чтения
инициализиуем строку a нулями (используем memset или аналоги)
открываем файл/файлы
пока есть строки
  читаем текущую строку в b
  дописываем нули до конца строки (это важная часть!)
  делаем xor  => a = a xor b;
конец цикла
вывод a
закрываем файл/файлы
```

что такое `a = a xor b;` - это посимвольный ксор. где то так

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
   a[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
}
```

и нужно именно на все символы, а не по длине.

дописываение нулей - это где то так (писано на скорую руку)

```
for (int i = strlen(b); i < 256; i++)
   b[i] = 0;
```

можно конечно обнулить строку сразу, а потом читать, но я бы так не делал. процедура чтения может добавить левые символы (теоретически).

Answer (score 2):

1. Может, оно по памяти вылетает? В условии N < 50000, а у вас массив всего на 25002
2. Раз уж пишете на C++, пользуйтесь STL. В вашем случае поможет [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).

Answer (score 1):

На C++ без stl не пишут уже миллион лет.

Вот [решение](http://ideone.com/uNPO0k), основанное на map, реализовал идею [[@fori1ton](/users/5577/fori1ton)](/users/5577/fori1ton):

```
string s;
map<string, int> quantities;
while (cin >> s)
{
    if (s == "#")
        break;
    quantities[s]++;
}

auto it = find_if(quantities.begin(), quantities.end(),
                  [](pair<string, int> kvp) { return kvp.second == 1; });
```

Решение не опирается на чётность количества неуникальных строк.

[Альтернативное решение](http://ideone.com/WFo2yA), с множествами:

```
string s;
unordered_set<string> unique, multiple;
while (cin >> s)
{
    if (s == "#")
        break;
    if (multiple.find(s) != multiple.end())
        continue;
    auto founduniq = unique.find(s);
    if (founduniq != unique.end())
    {
        unique.erase(founduniq);
        multiple.insert(s);
        continue;
    }
    unique.insert(s);
}
```

Comment: в первой примере решения я бы использовать stl::find_if, а не цикл for, если уже пишете на stl.

Comment: @KoVadim: и то правда :-) Обновил ответ. ЗЫ: я бы сказал, не на stl, а на C++.